# "Negative" SQL (postgres) query

Tags: node.js, postgresql

i need some help for a SQL query. Because I am new to this domain, i could not really explain google what i am trying to do, I didn't find any proper answer yet. Is it even possible with my tables?

I want to receive all the Threads (id, name), which are not my own Threads and which are not voted by me already. (i.e Threads i can vote)

The database looks like this:

```
Threads
+----+-------------+---------+
| id | thread_name | user_id |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 | Soccer      |       1 |
|  2 | Running     |       1 |
|  3 | Swimming    |       2 |
+----+-------------+---------+

User
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Marcel |
|  2 | Marc   |
|  3 | Susy   |
+----+--------+

Votes
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | thread_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 |         1 |       3 |
|  2 |         1 |       2 |
|  3 |         2 |       3 |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

Example:

- If User 1 makes the query, he should receive the thread 3 because it is not his own and he did not voted yet.
- User 2 should receive thread 2
- User 4 should receive all the threads

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, name FROM threads as t
LEFT JOIN votes as v ON v.thread_id = t.id
WHERE (v.user_id != USER_ID OR v.user_id IS NULL)
AND t.user_id != USER_ID
```

I am using Sequelize (Node.js ORM). pgAdmin gives me the following (simplified) as schema - hope this helps:

```
-- Table: "threads"
-- DROP TABLE "threads";

CREATE TABLE "threads"
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "user_id" integer,
  CONSTRAINT "threads_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "threads_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
      REFERENCES "users" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "threads"
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Table: "votes"
-- DROP TABLE "votes";

CREATE TABLE "votes"
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "user_id" integer,
  "thread_id" integer,
  CONSTRAINT "votes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "votes_thread_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("thread_id")
      REFERENCES "threads" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "votes_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
      REFERENCES "users" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "votes"
  OWNER TO postgres;


-- Table: "users"
-- DROP TABLE "users";

CREATE TABLE "users"
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  username character varying(255),
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
   ALTER TABLE "users"
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

Thank you.

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Ok, and what did you try ?

Comment: @MarcelSchulze can you also give schema of you tables i.e. \d <table name> ?

Comment: @shivams i am not sure, can you have a look at my update? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
select t.id from threads as t where t.user_id != USER_ID and t.id not in 
(select v.thread_id from votes as v where v.user_id = USER_ID);
```

Comment: thank you. Looks like it is working this way. Never thought about using two select statements. Is it even possible with one?

Comment: @MarcelSchulze I cannot say for sure. I think for a little while to edit your query but was unable to do. So i rewrite it this way. I hope this will take you forward in your task which is what matter at the end ;)